# Extract page number from text TSQL using string methods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract page number enclosed between `<Page_No>10</Page_No>` ie retrieve 10.

Text is like

```
 <root>
  <Image>
    <File_image>07Feb13Kol030.jpg</File_image>
    <Page_no>10</Page_no>
    <Logo>N</Logo>
    <Photo>N</Photo>
    <Color>B</Color>
  </Image>
</root>
```

This is not working . Only FIRST two characters are returned.

```
select 

substring(convert(varchar(max),fileimage),charindex(convert(varchar(max),fileimage),'Page_no')+8,2) 

from mytable
```

Please help

Comment: Is your text always XML?

Comment: yes , that is why i am converting to varchar

Comment: Valid xml has a single root element. Your XML either has multiple root elements or no root element.

Comment: I've updated my Fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1161/5 -- Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CROSS APPLY` -- here is mockup to help:

```
SELECT 
   x.value('(Page_no)[1]', 'int') AS 'Page_no'
FROM XMLTable x
CROSS APPLY x.myXMLField.nodes('/root/Image') 
  n(x)
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1161/5).  Depending on the full structure of your XML, you may need to change .nodes('/') to the parent node.

I've updated my answer to include your field names if that helps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Janosch Worschitz](http://janisch.worschitz.org), TSQL has had [XQuery support since 2005](https://janosch.woschitz.org/parse-xml-in-t-sql-via-xquery/), so instead of doing `substring` and other oddities on the XML, try this:

```
SELECT
    Page  = item.value'(//Page_no), INT)
FROM @XML.nodes('//root/Image') AS Facility(item);
```

Comment: name of the column is fileimage containing xml text, where should it be in query...plz help

Comment: That's not your **root** element, please post your entire XML document in your question and I'll help you.

Comment: please check , i have posted